# Scala - Getting sequence id of elements during map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Scala newbie question.
I want to map a list to another list but I want to every object to know its sequence number.
In the following simple code, what is the right alternative to the usage of var v?

```
class T (s: String, val sequence:Int)
val stringList = List("a","b","C")
var v  = 0
val tList = stringList.map(s => { v=v+1; new T(s, v);})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zipWithIndex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@zipWithIndex:Seq[(A,Int)]) to get a tuple for each element containing the actual element and the index, then just map that tuple to your object:

```
List("a", "b", "C")
  .zipWithIndex
  .map(e => new T(e._1, e._2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val tList = List.tabulate(stringList.length)(idx => new T(stringList(idx), idx))
```